# Como puedo cambiar "\n" por "\r\n" en un char en c++

Tags: c++, c++builder

Al leer un fichero con el siguiente código:

```
std::ifstream t;
int length;
t.open(fileName_char);      // open input file
t.seekg(0, std::ios::end);    // go to the end
length = t.tellg();           // report location (this is the length)
t.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);    // go back to the beginning
char *buffer = new char[length];    // allocate memory for a *buffer of appropriate dimension
t.read(buffer, length);       // read the whole file into the buffer
t.close();
```

En el buffer se guardan los saltos de línea como "\n". (Ej: "Hola\nMundo").
Bien, el problema viene cuando quiero obtener el código HASH SHA1 con el siguiente código:

```
TIdHashSHA1* sha1CODE = new TIdHashSHA1;
GeneratedHASHcode = sha1CODE->HashStringAsHex(buffer);
delete sha1CODE;
```

La función sha1CODE->HashStringAsHex() no codifica de la misma manera "\n" que "\r\n" de manera que me genera un código HASH SHA1 distinto al que tengo guardado en la base de datos. Finalmente cuando comparo el 'CodigoHASHgenerado' con el 'CodigoHASH_base_de_datos' me indica, evidentemente, que no hay coincidencia y me da error.

¿Como puedo cambiar "\n" por "\r\n" en la variable buffer?

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Hola. En Windows un salto de línea en un fichero son dos caracteres y no uno como en linux. Así que por cada salto de línea tienes un \r y luego un \n: Dos caracteres. Lo que podrías hacer es una vez leído, eliminar los \r de la cadena recorriéndola caracter a caracter y copiando todos los caracteres salvo ese. Obviamente la función calcula hashes distintos porque tu buffer tiene más caracteres. Uno más por cada salto de línea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acuerdo a esta [respuesta](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/33482/). Cuando se abre un archivo en modo texto, por defecto \r\n se convierte a \n, para evitar esto, abre el archivo en modo binario, que según la [documentación](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/) sería de la siguiente manera:

```
t.open(fileName_char, ios::binary);
```

Comment: Esto ha solucionado mi problema de una. Mi archivo era binario desde un incio pero no sabia que tenia que especificar la apertura en binario. MUCHAS GRACIAS

Answer (score 1):

Para empezar, evita complicarte la vida calculando el tamaño del archivo manualmente con `seekg` y `tellg` para crear un búfer en memoria dinámica del que te tendrás que hacer cargo posteriormente. Usa las herramientas de C++:

```
if (std::ifstream f{"test.txt"})
{
    std::string buffer;
    buffer.reserve(1000);

    using iterador = std::istreambuf_iterator<char>;
    for (iterador begin(f), end(); begin != end; ++begin)
    {
        if (*begin == '\n')
            buffer.push_back('\r');
        buffer.push_back(*begin);
    }
}
```

Si te preocupa que el búfer sea un `std::string` que esté realojando memoria continuamente, puedes reservarle una cantidad de memoria arbitraria moderadamente grande (como he hecho yo).

Al comprobar carácter a carácter la lectura, si detectas un salto de línea (`\n`) le añades un retorno de carro (`\r`) antes de hacer la inserción en el búfer.

Comment: Probé a hacer esto, pero el problema es que el archivo que leo es demasiado grande y se produce una sobrecarga en el buffer. De todas formas me has dado una idea para modificar otros buffer que uso en el programa. MUCHAS GRACIAS

Comment: Cuando dices que "*se produce una sobrecarga en el búfer*" ¿Te refieres al `std::string buffer;`?

Comment: Si, me refiero al std::string buffer. Me da un error de "access violation" cuando sobre pasa ciertas lineas del archivo. Por algunas pruebas que he estado haciendo el error se produce rondando la linea 500.000 del archivo.

Comment: ¿Y no tenías "access violation" al hacer `new char[X];` con X ≥ 500000?